# Make compact list of records in FreePascal?

Tags: freepascal

I have structure which is big in memory. It is TList; each item is TMyObject and TMyObject holds Data field which is record (with n fields: integer, boolean). List may have 1.000.000 items.

I want to make list compact: I want to have list not of TMyObject but list of record, each list item must be record. So no proxy TMyObjects are made. Records are saved in list as is.

How to do this "list class" w/o making new big code, w/o making my own Insert/Delete/Add, w/o reallocating records in Insert/Delete/Add?

(using FPC 3.0, Lazarus)

Comment: For instance, you could use `TFPGList<T>` http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/fgl/tfpglist.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is what i want, pls post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options but I suspect the most appropriate would be [`TFPGList<T>`](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/fgl/tfpglist.html).